# login form using Membership API in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, authentication, asp.net-membership

I am new In ASP.NET,

I want to create to Login Form using Membership API, i am unable to login with my credential,

here, is my code snippet for

`LoginForm.aspx.cs`

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(Username.Text, Password.Text))
    {
        Response.Write("Welcome " + Username.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Sorry Login Failed ");
    }
}
```

i created Registration Form using Membership API

here, is my code snippet for  `RegistrationForm.aspx.cs`

```
 protected void AddUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MembershipCreateStatus result;
    try
    {
        MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text, TextBox5.Text, true, out result);
        if (result == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
        {
            Response.Write("Successfulley created");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Fail to Register");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        Response.Write(err.Message);
    }
}
```

when i register new user in RegistrationForm i get output as `Successfulley created`, but after Registration when i do Login with Registerd username and password i get output as `Sorry Login Failed`

Comment: @dhavel: The most unimportant part of your question is in bold :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dhaval try this,

```
protected void SubmitClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(Username.Text, Password.Text))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Username.Text, true);
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Username.Text, true);

            Response.Redirect("NextPage.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Sorry Login Failed ");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        Response.Write(err.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to use this?

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie
```

Comment: i want to do successful login, with register user, what code segment should i add ? in my `LoginForm.aspx.cs` file.

Comment: Give this a read 4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110701-1.shtml there are 3 Parts.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `website administration tool`from the right hand top corner from the VS solution explorer and you will see something as seen in below screenshot and if you can see created users you will have a checkbox beside it if it checked you can login otherwise make it checked and then you can able to login successfully.

[image]